# New tag for Elastic's "App Search"?

Tags: support, tags

If I understand the rules correctly, here is the right location to kindly ask for creating a tag on Stack Overflow?

I suggest to add [swiftype-app-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftype-app-search) and as synonym [elastic-app-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-app-search).

It is a relatively new but rather software by Elastic based on [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) whose documentation is quite monopolized, that why I think it make sense to have an appropriate tag for that. Since the tag [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) and [app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app) is so prominent, I have big troubles to identify Stack Overflow questions which are really about **Elastic's App Search**, another reason why I think a new tag makes sense.
I would of course go ahead with retagging existing questions.

A possible definition:

> **Elastic App Search** is a Java software based on Elasticsearch and distributed by Swiftype, a subsidary of Elastic. The software offers a set of APIs and dashboards expanding and simplifying the Elasticsearch functionality when it comes to features like word stemming, automatic typo correction of search terms, and the definition of synonyms.

**External sources:**

- https://www.elastic.co/products/app-search
- https://www.elastic.co/downloads/app-search
- https://swiftype.com/app-search
- https://github.com/elastic/app-search-php

**Disclaimer:** I am not in any kind affiliated with the companies, I just want to get it running at my client and for that I love to be able to find the relevant stuff about the topic on SO.

**Preliminary list of questions for tag [elastic-app-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-app-search)**

- [JSON.net deserialize object nested data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619432/)
- [looking to implement a search feature into my website from Swifttype.com where someone on the site can easily search for anything thats available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349342/)
- [Solr Result Ranking modifications to a particlar query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54026915/)
- [How can you apply a named scope to Tire search results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152505/)

I just found the tag [swiftype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftype), so my request would rather be: Could somebody define the synonyms [swiftype-app-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftype-app-search) and [elastic-app-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elastic-app-search), please?

Comment: I added a list of examples plus I found a synonym, see my edit.

Comment: @B--rian I'm not convinced by this list of 4 questions to actually need a tag [elastic-app-search] at the present time.

Comment: @Coeur. So how many questions do you want me to list to be convinced?

Comment: @B--rian you don't need to convince me specifically: once you've convinced **one** person with 1500 reputation, it will be enough to have the tag. Try asking some of the people who've been posting those questions/answers.

Comment: What I meant is: What is the rule-of-thumb how many questions I should collect to convince one of them. Side remark: I find it rather interesting that such an important feature like tagging requires so much reputation. Is it misused so often?

Comment: The recommendation is 10 questions if I recall correctly. The theoretical minimum is 1 question: it needs to be good and precisely about the topic covered by the new tag, with a hint that a trend is coming (for instance, when a new version of a popular product is released). As for the 1500 reputation threshold, it's about 75% of the reputation required to freely edit any post on Stack Overflow (2000 reputation). But again, the creation only needs to be done once, by one person, so it's generally not a big deal. So simply ask around the other users of Elastic Search for instance.